# Unity XR VR Issue with Inputs and GetDeviceWithCharacteristics syntax possible?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I had to comment out a bunch of my code but it came down to this with 2 errors. The issue seems to be with the line that uses 'GetDevicesWithCharacteristics' because that is where the errors point too but i checked the documentation and it seems good. I also checked the line above and i'm not sure if the ', lefthandedcontrollers;' that i added after the fact to follow the documentation(which wasn't actually the problem).

I'm inexperienced so please forgive me if this is a simple mistake.

```
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.XR;

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class controlerInputScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject gameObjectToMove;
    public int scale = 3;


    var leftHandedControllers = new List<UnityEngine.XR.InputDevice>();
    InputDeviceCharacteristics leftcontrollerdesiredCharacteristics = UnityEngine.XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics.HeldInHand | UnityEngine.XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics.Left | UnityEngine.XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics.Controller, leftHandedControllers;
    InputDevices.GetDevicesWithCharacteristics(XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics leftcontrollerdesiredCharacteristics, List<InputDevice> leftHandedControllers);


    // var rightHandedControllers = new List<UnityEngine.XR.InputDevice>();
    // var rightcontrollerdesiredCharacteristics = UnityEngine.XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics.HeldInHand | UnityEngine.XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics.Right | UnityEngine.XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics.Controller;
    // UnityEngine.XR.InputDevices.GetDevicesWithCharacteristics(rightcontrollerdesiredCharacteristics, rightHandedControllers);


    // if (leftHandedControllers > 1) || (rightHandedControllers >1){
    //     Debug.Log("DEBUG: ERROR: More than one Left or Right handed controller detected!")
    // }

    //assign Controlllers
    InputDevice leftController = leftHandedControllers[0];
    //InputDevice rightController = rightHandedControllers[0];

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 p = this.transform.position;
        float leftTriggerState;
        if (leftController.TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.trigger, out leftTriggerState)){
            p.y = scale * leftTriggerState;
            gameObjectToMove.transform.position = p;
        }
     
    //     float rightGripState;
    //     if (rightController.TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.grip, out rightGripState)){
    //         p.x = scale* rightGripState;
    //         gameObjectToMove.transform.position = p;
    //     }
    }
}
```

The Errors were:

```
Assets\ConQuestV3\controlerInputScript.cs(58,47): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Assets\ConQuestV3\controlerInputScript.cs(58,156): error CS1519: Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm talking about those lines

```
var leftHandedControllers = new List<UnityEngine.XR.InputDevice>();
InputDeviceCharacteristics leftcontrollerdesiredCharacteristics = UnityEngine.XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics.HeldInHand | UnityEngine.XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics.Left | UnityEngine.XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics.Controller, leftHandedControllers;
InputDevices.GetDevicesWithCharacteristics(XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics leftcontrollerdesiredCharacteristics, List<InputDevice> leftHandedControllers);
```

in the second line, are you sure about this

> , leftHandedControllers;

because this syntax is incorrect and does not have any semantics also.

In the third line, what are you trying to do in the parameters! you are redefining the previous variables in the function parameters!

I believe your code should be like:

```
var leftHandedControllers = new List<UnityEngine.XR.InputDevice>();
InputDeviceCharacteristics leftcontrollerdesiredCharacteristics = UnityEngine.XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics.HeldInHand | UnityEngine.XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics.Left | UnityEngine.XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics.Controller;
InputDevices.GetDevicesWithCharacteristics(leftcontrollerdesiredCharacteristics, leftHandedControllers);
```

Comment: I did some more checking and determined that the error comes from the line GetDevicesWithCharacteristics. I was also able to duplicate the error with the alternate method of getting controllers GetDevicesWithRole. When I uncommented them, both errors happened twice. This seems like a syntax error, but i appear to be following the documentation to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: ok, if you can please share this documentation, it may help to check if you are missing  something

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is still throwing an error is because `InputDevices.GetDevicesWithCharacteristics` only works when inside a function like `void start` or `void update`. I found that if you place some of the code that's outside any function on the inside your `void start` method works perfectly fine.

```
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.XR;

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class controlerInputScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject gameObjectToMove;
    public int scale = 3;

    InputDevice leftController;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        var leftHandedControllers = new List<UnityEngine.XR.InputDevice>();
        InputDeviceCharacteristics leftcontrollerdesiredCharacteristics = UnityEngine.XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics.HeldInHand | UnityEngine.XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics.Left | UnityEngine.XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics.Controller, leftHandedControllers;
        InputDevices.GetDevicesWithCharacteristics(XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics leftcontrollerdesiredCharacteristics, List < InputDevice > leftHandedControllers);


        // var rightHandedControllers = new List<UnityEngine.XR.InputDevice>();
        // var rightcontrollerdesiredCharacteristics = UnityEngine.XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics.HeldInHand | UnityEngine.XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics.Right | UnityEngine.XR.InputDeviceCharacteristics.Controller;
        // UnityEngine.XR.InputDevices.GetDevicesWithCharacteristics(rightcontrollerdesiredCharacteristics, rightHandedControllers);


        // if (leftHandedControllers > 1) || (rightHandedControllers >1){
        //     Debug.Log("DEBUG: ERROR: More than one Left or Right handed controller detected!")
        // }

        //assign Controlllers
        InputDevice leftController = leftHandedControllers[0];
        //InputDevice rightController = rightHandedControllers[0];
    }

    // // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 p = this.transform.position;
        float leftTriggerState;
        if (leftController.TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.trigger, out leftTriggerState))
        {
            p.y = scale * leftTriggerState;
            gameObjectToMove.transform.position = p;
        }

        //     float rightGripState;
        //     if (rightController.TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.grip, out rightGripState)){
        //         p.x = scale* rightGripState;
        //         gameObjectToMove.transform.position = p;
        //     }
    }
}
```